# Unusual meaning of 終わる or just a parsing failure?

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

Regarding young people who don't know the date of the end of the pacific war:

> 中学校や高校の歴史の授業は、太平洋戦争を教える前に**終わってしまうこと**が多いため、知らない人が増えているのだと思います。
>   I think the number of people who don't know (the date) is increasing because *there are many things that will finish* before middle school and high school history classes teach about the war.

I can't make any sense out of the part in bold. What is coming to and end? What does こと refer to?

Comment: You already have a good answer below, so I will say this here.  「中学校や高校の歴史の授業」 here actually refers to the same thing as the "academic year".  It just (conveniently) ends before you get to the WWII part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off to a good start.  There are just a couple of things.  I know you said that this sentence was in a context of students not knowing the date for the end of the Pacific War.  However, just looking at this one sentence outside of that context, I would construe it rather differently.

The core of the sentence is

> 知らない人が増えている
>   There are *more and more people* who are uninformed.

Here "more and more people" is my way of handling "人が増えている".

The speaker wants us to know that this is their opinion, so they add

> ...のだと思います
>   I think it is the case that ...

Just putting these two parts together, we get

> 知らない人が増えているのだと思います
>   I think it's the case that there are more and more people who are uninformed.

So, we could ask the question, "why does the speaker have this opinion?"  Well, they told us already, that's the part of the sentence that precedes ため.  Namely,

> 中学校や高校の歴史の授業は、太平洋戦争を教える前に終わってしまうことが多い

Here is where is seems you got a bit more stuck about what's happening in the sentence.  This portion of the sentence can be broken down into four parts.

> ことが多い
>   [Something happens] a lot.

What happens a lot?

> [何か]が終わってしまう
>   [something] *unfortunately* comes to an end

I'm using "unfortunately" here to get across the idea communicated by てしまう.  I only know to do that because of the larger context of the meaning.

The something here is

> 中学校や高校の歴史の授業
>   Middle school and high school history classes

Putting these three things together gives us

> 中学校や高校の歴史の授業が終わってしまことが多い
>   Middle school and high school history classes unfortunately *frequently* come to an end

Notice that I use "frequently" to get across the idea of ことが多い.

Now the final part, why is this a concern?  The context you were talking about was regarding students not knowing certain dates.  So, the final piece of the puzzle is

> 太平洋戦争を教える前に
>   before they teach about the Pacific War

So, putting this forth piece together with the three previous pieces, we get

> 中学校や高校の歴史の授業は、太平洋戦争を教える前に終わってしまうことが多い
>   Middle school and high school history classes unforunately frequently come to an end before they teach about the Pacific War

Now putting it all together, you get

> I think that there are more and more people who are uninformed [about the Pacific War] because middle school and high school history classes unforunately frequently come to an end before the Pacific War gets taught**.

Technically, there's no passive construction in the sentence, but I'm just trying to render the last part a bit more smoothly into English.

Answer (score 2):

Parse it like this:

- 中学校や高校の歴史の授業は、: middle and high school lessons in history: TOPIC
- 太平洋戦争を教える : teaching the pacific war
- 前に : before
- 終わってしまう : end
- ことが多いため、: it often happens that CAUSE
- 知らない人が増えている : people who don't know are increasing
- のだと思います。: I think

Read to TOPIC, then read the CAUSE in reverse order, then the remainder in reverse order.

- Because middle and high school lessons in history often end before teaching the pacific war, I think people who don't know are increasing.

ことが多い : This is a very common expression for things (abstract こと things, not もの concrete things) happening a lot.